# ScrollViewDidEndDecelerating gets called every time when I select cell

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I know that it would be repeated question but I really stuck on it. My first CollectionView’s each cell has another collectionView as a subview. My first CollectionView has three cells with same width and height and my Second collectionView has 27 cells. I want to show edge of next and previous cells at second cells of the first collection view and got it using the ScrollViewDidEndDecelerating delegate method of the uiscrollview but the problem is the he gets called even simple touch on any collectionview item. Please help me, how do I get rid of this shit? 
If anyone wouldn’t get my point I can share code as well.